# How to access variables in another module with a string?

Tags: python, variables

Assuming I have a module named Test1.py, and in it there are variables, say,

```
something = 10
apple = 5
```

I don't know these variables beforehand, they would be dynamically added from another module. So, how would I be able to access these variables in a **different** module given the variable's name as a string?

For example, I'd like to use the string `'apple'` to access the `apple` variable from that module. In general, something like this:

```
# AnotherModule.py

import Test1

var = input('Variable: ')
print(Test1.var)
```

How to make that work if I enter `apple` as an input, and the result should be 5, since `apple` is 5 in the other module.

Comment: `getattr(Test1, var)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getattr` for this:

```
getattr(Test1, var)
```